# Div within Div hides when outer div animates

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a parent div with height 0 and a child div within, but on top using z-index.  I want this child div when clicked to expand the height of the parent div.  Works great really but the inner div disappears behind the other divs parallel to the parent div and when the animation is done it shows it back on top again.  So basically, during the animation the child div hides behind the other sections.  Here is my code:

```
    <!-- Seccion on top of animated div -->
    <section class="backgroundBlack">
        <div class"indexContacto">
        <p>lorem ipsum other stuff here</p>       
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Contact Section -->

    <hr class="hrBlackToGrey" />

    <!-- Redes Sociales -->
    <section id="seccionGrid" class="colorGrey seccionGridOn">

            <div id="hex4" class="hex hex-4">
                <div class="inner">
                        <h5>Síguenos a trevés de redes sociales</h5>
                </div>  
                <div class="corner-1"></div>
                <div class="corner-2"></div>        
            </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Redes Sociales -->

    <hr class="hrGreyToBlack" />

    <!-- Footer -->
    <section class="sectionBlack">
        <div id="footer">
        <p>lorem ipsum stuff</p>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Here is my JS:

```
<!-- Scripts Header -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Move Hexes Around -->
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#hex4").click(function() {
            <!--$("#hex1").toggleClass('hex-1-Off', 1000);-->
            $("#seccionGrid").toggleClass('seccionGridOff', 1000);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my css:

```css
#seccionGrid{
    position: relative;
}

.seccionGridOn {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height:0px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.seccionGridOff{
    height:500px;
}

.hex {
    width:150px;
    height:86px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;           
    -webkit-background-size: auto 173px;                            
    -moz-background-size: auto 173px;                           
    -ms-background-size: auto 173px;                            
    -o-background-size: auto 173px;                         
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    margin-top: -43px;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: visible;
}

    .hex.hex-gap {
        margin-left: 86px;
    }

    .hex a {
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        text-indent:-9999em;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }

    .hex .corner-1,
    .hex .corner-2 {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background: inherit;                                
        z-index:-2;                     
        overflow:hidden;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -o-backface-visibility: hidden;         
        backface-visibility: hidden;            
    }

    .hex .corner-1 {
        z-index:-1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
        transform: rotate(60deg);
    }

    .hex .corner-2 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
        transform: rotate(-60deg);
    }

    .hex .corner-1:before,
    .hex .corner-2:before {
        width: 173px;
        height: 173px;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background: inherit;
      top:0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      background: inherit;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -o-backface-visibility: hidden; 
        backface-visibility: hidden;                  
    }           


    .hex .corner-1:before {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(-87px, 0px);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(-87px, 0px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(-87px, 0px);
        -o-transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(-87px, 0px);
        transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(-87px, 0px);    
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }           

    .hex .corner-2:before {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-48px, -11px);
        -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-48px, -11px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-48px, -11px);
        -o-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-48px, -11px);
        transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-48px, -11px);   
        bottom:0;
    }       



    .hex .inner {       
        color:#eee;
    }

    .hex h4 {
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;        
        margin:0;           
    }

    .hex h5 {
        font-color: #333;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;        
        margin:0;
        font-size: 20px;            
    }

    .hex hr {
        border:0;
        border-top:1px solid #eee;
        width:60%;
        margin:15px auto;
    }

    .hex p {
        font-size:16px;
        font-family: 'Kotta One', serif;
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }


    .hex.hex-4 {
        background: #ffb400;
    }


.hex-1-Off {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 86px;
    margin-left: 86px;
}

.hexCenter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;

}
```

Any ideas how to keep my hex up on top?

**FIDDLE TO DEMO THE ISSUE: http://jsfiddle.net/xQVjq/**

:EDIT:
Just in case someone wants to do this without removing the div from the seccion I was able to maintain the div on top during the animation using this:

.css('overflow', 'visible')

right after the toggle class...

Hope this helps someone out.
:EDIT:

Comment: Plugging this lot into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful.

Comment: For this big code, its better to show a demo of your code using fiddle or something!!!

Comment: is this http://jsfiddle.net/9f95z/ the desired result?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U7gjX/ - Ok, I jsFiddled it- Notice the hexagon hides durin the animation but I would think the z-index attribute should keep it on top no?

Comment: It *is* on top, but its clipped by the animation itself which will set the element's overflow.

Comment: Hi Melc, yes that is the result visually that I desire.  Was your only edit commenting out position relative?

Answer (score 1):

As the div animates jQuery sets its `overflow` property to `hidden` (else it wouldn't be able to restrict how high it appears). Then, on completion, it returns the `overflow` to its previous value.

If you move the hex button outside of the expanding/collapsing section it will work.

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/NChK3/

Comment: Thanks, want to volume up your answer but my rep is nothing as I am new to stackoverflow...

Comment: I guess I should have expanded on what I was hoping to do.  I wanted the hex to move down as center in that section with the animation using top:50%  - outside of hidding it does not work.  Also what melc did by commenting out the postiton relative messes things up in the real big html as there are many sections and I want the hex centered on that section.   Any more ideas?

Comment: Oh I think I got it by adding this to jquery - .css('overflow', 'visible')  right after the toggle class - thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you move the Hex outside the div you wont have the issue, and it will look just as good

http://jsfiddle.net/xQVjq/1/

```
<!-- Redes Sociales -->
<div id="hex4" class="hex hex-4">
            <div class="inner">
                    <h5>Síguenos a trevés de redes sociales</h5>
            </div>  
            <div class="corner-1"></div>
            <div class="corner-2"></div>        
        </div>
<section id="seccionGrid" class="colorGrey seccionGridOn">


</section>
<!-- Redes Sociales -->
```

Comment: Thanks, want to volume up your answer but my rep is nothing as I am new to stackoverflow...